# Python - Convert a roman numeral to an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, roman-numerals

I've tried the following *Python 3* code that transform from Roman to Integer.

The code is working fine at a glance. But there are certain problem happened when I input `X`, `V` or related to `X` and `V` value.

For example: when I try `V` the code is not working but for `IV` showing correct value.

My code:

```
class Solution(object):
   def romanToInt(self, s):
      """
      :type s: str
      :rtype: int
      """
      roman = {'I':1,'V':5,'X':10,'L':50,'C':100,'D':500,'M':1000,'IV':4,'IX':9,'XL':40,'XC':90,'CD':400,'CM':900}
      i = 0
      num = 0
      while i < len(s):
         if i+1<len(s) and s[i:i+2] in roman:
            num+=roman[s[i:i+2]]
            i+=2
         else:
            #print(i)
            num+=roman[s[i]]
            i+=1
      return num
ob1 = Solution()

message = str(input("Please enter your roman number: "))
if message <= ("MMMCMXCIX"):
   print (ob1.romanToInt(message))
else:
    print ("Try again")
```

I've set the condition which is, if the input roman number is equal or less than `MMMCMXCIX`, it will print the roman number; else it will print `Try again`.

The problem is when I input `X`, `V` or related to `X` and `V` value the output is showing `Try again`

Please help me to understand where I went wrong.

Comment: What is this line supposed to do `if message <= ("MMMCMXCIX")`? It is comparing the user input to a string. Don't you need to convert both to integers first before comparing them?

Comment: `if message <= ("MMMCMXCIX"):`

This line is comparing strings which means you're comparing the first character of message with the first character of "MMMCMXCIX" so any first character of message which is after M in the alphabet will cause "Try Again" to be printed

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are comparing the strings instead first convert the roman to int than check

```
class Solution(object):
   def romanToInt(self, s):
      """
      :type s: str
      :rtype: int
      """
      roman = {'I':1,'V':5,'X':10,'L':50,'C':100,'D':500,'M':1000,'IV':4,'IX':9,'XL':40,'XC':90,'CD':400,'CM':900}
      i = 0
      num = 0
      while i < len(s):
         if i+1<len(s) and s[i:i+2] in roman:
            num+=roman[s[i:i+2]]
            i+=2
         else:
            #print(i)
            num+=roman[s[i]]
            i+=1
      return num
ob1 = Solution()

message = str(input("Please enter your roman number: "))
# converting to integer than comparing the value of "MMMCMXCIX"
if ob1.romanToInt(message) <= 8999:
   print (ob1.romanToInt(message))
else:
    print ("Try again")
```

Answer (score 1):

In the end its just an addition of numbers, you just need to figure if they need to be interpreted positive or negativ:

```
roman = {'I':1,'V':5,'X':10,'L':50,'C':100,'D':500,'M':1000,'IV':4,'IX':9,'XL':40,'XC':90,'CD':400,'CM':900}

def roman2Dec(inp):
    inpNum = [roman[x] for x in inp]
    return sum([-x if i < len(inpNum)-1 and x < inpNum[i+1] else x for i, x in enumerate(inpNum)])

for nums in [('IX', 9), ('XL', 40), ('LXI', 61), ('MMMCMXCIX', 3999)]:
    result = roman2Dec(nums[0])
    print result == nums[1]
```

Output:

```
True
True
True
True
```

Answer (score 1):

Listed below some approaches below with their respective runtimes to convert roman numerals to integers.

**Solution 1: (Approx Runtime = 52ms)**

```
def romanToInt(self, s: str) -> int:
 s = s.upper()
 roman = {'I':1, 'V':5, 'X':10, 'L':50, 'C':100, 'D':500, 'M':1000 }    
 num = 0

 for i in range(len(s)):

    if i!= len(s)-1 and roman[s[i]] < roman[s[i+1]]:
         num += roman[s[i]]*-1
    else:
         num += roman[s[i]]

  return num
```

**Solution 2: (Approx Runtime = 60ms)**

```
def romanToInt(self, s: str) -> int:
 s = s.upper()
 roman = {'I':1, 'V':5, 'X':10, 'L':50, 'C':100, 'D':500, 'M':1000 }    
 num = 0

 s = s.replace("IV", "IIII").replace("IX", "VIIII")
 s = s.replace("XL", "XXXX").replace("XC", "LXXXX")
 s = s.replace("CD", "CCCC").replace("CM", "DCCCC")

 for x in s:
    num += roman[x]

 return num
```

**Solution 3: (Approx Runtime = 48ms)**

```
def romanToInt(self, s: str) -> int:
 s = s.upper()
 roman = {'I':1, 'V':5, 'X':10, 'L':50, 'C':100, 'D':500, 'M':1000 }    
 num = 0

 for i in range(len(s)-1):
    if roman[s[i]] < roman[s[i+1]]:
        num += roman[s[i]]*-1
        continue

     num += roman[s[i]]

  num +=roman[s[-1]]

  return num
```

The simplest solution appears to be the best at times :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the problem was caused because you compared string rather than first transform to int and then do the comparison.

Other approach that you can try is:

```
def romanToInt(s):
  d = {'m': 1000, 'd': 500, 'c': 100, 'l': 50, 'x': 10, 'v': 5, 'i': 1}
  n = [d[i] for i in s.lower() if i in d]
  return sum([i if i>=n[min(j+1, len(n)-1)] else -i for j,i in enumerate(n)])

print(romanToInt('X')) # 10
print(romanToInt('V')) # 5
print(romanToInt('IV')) # 4
print(romanToInt('XV')) # 15
```

In my opinion both are more pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this question in a simple way as below.

This question can be solved with the idea that every roman numeral in the roman number are arranged in descending order if that's not the case then it is a special case like 'IV', 'IX', 'XL', .....

In the below the above peculiar case is handled by the `if` statement.

```
def romanToInt(s):
    mapping  = {
        'I': 1,
        'V': 5,
        'X': 10,
        'L': 50,
        'C': 100,
        'D': 500,
        'M': 1000,
        }
        
    min_ = None
    total = 0
    for c in s:
        val = mapping[c]
        print(val)
        if min_ and val > min_:
            total -= min_*2
        else:
            min_ = val
        total += val
                
    return total
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def romanToInt(s):    
    p=z=0
    for i in map('IVXLCDM'.find,s[::-1]):x=[1,5][i%2]*10**(i//2);z+=[x,-x][p>x];p=x
    return z
```